# Most efficient searching algorithm in a table

Tags: data, performance-tuning, searching

I am completely new in Mathematica (and in data analysis in general) and I find it really useful, although I still do not use it properly.

I have the following question related to data manipulation:
 I have a huge table (115 * 100000), and I want to make queries of the type "look for the row in `TABLE` such that its column number 1 has the value `0.124`, column number 3 has the value `45345.5` etc.. (if it helps, the row verifying such a conditions is unique). So far, I am doing it through `Select` in the following way:

```
Select[TABLE, #[[1]] == value1 && #[[3]] == value2 &]
```

I suspect that there is a faster way to do it, is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If the row is unique you can use `SelectFirst` to stop looking after you've found the row.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Note that using Select can be slow relative to pattern matching with Cases, however since you are using == to match a specific "Real" number, you should read this thread regarding the difference between exact and approximate numbers. (  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18485#18485 ).  When trying to select Real numbers it's often better to look for the difference. (i.e. Select[MyTable, Chop[#[[1]]-value1) == 0 && Chop[#[[3]]-value2] == 0 &] )

Comment: There are many ways to do this. That said, yours is fine. Whether others might be faster can only be determined by testing. Also this might depend on specifics of the table, such as whether or not it is a packed array of numbers. Given the uniqueness specification, the advice of @Pickett to use `SelectFirst` is also a good idea (though the improvement might not be huge, it's always good to bail out as soon as possible).

Comment: Related: [(8364804)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8364804/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `SelectFirst` approach is probably one of the easiest to read but just for fun here are a couple of other solutions. I'll start by generating a sample table `t0`.

```
t0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^5, 151}];
r0 = t0[[50000]];
```

Applying your method with `Select` is pretty fast. (Note that `SelectFirst` is faster for the unique case proportional to the position of the found row in the data so about 2x in this case). I've chosen vanilla `Select` for generality.

```
AbsoluteTiming[x1 = Select[t0, (#[[1]] == r0[[1]] && #[[3]] == r0[[3]]) &];]

(*{0.265200, Null}*)
```

Now I define a new function `pickRow` that does some trickery to create a mask for picking the proper row(s).  Chopping, as suggested by @rivercfd is a good idea since equal tolerances can lead to issues when testing for machine numbers. The `Unitize` converts all non-zero values to 1 and leaves zero 0. Thus, when I total, there are zeros in the positions of the found rows.

```
pickRow[data_, index_, values_] := 
 Pick[data, 
  Total[Unitize[Chop[Transpose[data[[All, index]]] - values]]], 0]

AbsoluteTiming[x2 = pickRow[t0, {1, 3}, r0[[{1, 3}]]];]

(* {0.062400, Null} *)
```

And of course if you can compile it is often worth trying for a speedup. I abandon `Pick` here because it is not among the list of compilable functions.

```
pickRowC = 
 Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {index, _Integer, 1}, {values, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{mask},
   mask = Total[Unitize[Chop[Transpose[data[[All, index]]] - values]]];
   data[[Flatten@Position[mask, 0]]]
   ]
  ];

AbsoluteTiming[x3 = pickRowC[t0, {1, 3}, r0[[{1, 3}]]];]

(* {0.015600, Null} *)

x1 == x2 == x3

(* True *)
```

The real benefits shine through when we scale the problem up. (Warning: I have 32GB ram so generating a matrix with 10^9 elements is no trouble for me but it might bring your machine down)

```
t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 1000}];
r = t[[500000]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 x1 = Select[
    t, (#[[1]] == r[[1]] && #[[3]] == r[[3]] && #[[200]] == 
        r[[200]] && #[[888]] == r[[888]]) &];]

(* {8.174414, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 x2 = pickRow[t, {1, 3, 200, 888}, r[[{1, 3, 200, 888}]]];]

(* {1.575603, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 x3 = pickRowC[t, {1, 3, 200, 888}, r[[{1, 3, 200, 888}]]];]

(* {0.140400, Null} *)

x1 == x2 == x3

(* True *)
```

At the request of @Aisamu here are the timings of the same operation using an algorithm with `Cases`.

```
patt = 
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[HoldPattern@_, #[[1]]], 
      Thread[#[[2]] -> #[[3]]]] &@({Length@#, {1, 3, 200, 
       888}, #[[{1, 3, 200, 888}]]}) &@r; AbsoluteTiming[
 x4 = Cases[t, patt];]

(* {9.859217, Null} *)

x1 == x2 == x3 == x4 

(* True *)
```

**NOTE**

I did some further testing on `SelectFirst` with my later large data set thinking I might be unfair in my comparison since I picked a value in the middle.  What I found surprised me, by setting `r` to `t[[1]]` I expected `SelectFirst` to bail out very quickly but instead it took around 10 seconds to complete. I think this happens because `Select` unpacks the packed table and with very large data this is time consuming.

Comment: You were right about bringing my machine down... Could you add this to your $10^9$ test? `patt = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[HoldPattern@_, #[[1]]], Thread[ #[[2]] -> #[[3]]]] &@({Length@#, {1, 3}, #[[{1, 3}]]}) &@r0; AbsoluteTiming[x4 = Cases[t0, patt];]`

Comment: You could earn a little bit of time by not extracting `r0[[1]]` and `r0[[3]]` every time. There's also this approach to try `t0[[t0[[All, {1, 3}]]~FirstPosition~{r0[[1]], r0[[3]]}]]]`

Comment: That was really helpful and instructive! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rojo that is a very clean and fast solution (though not quite as fast as the compiled function). I didn't even know about `FirstPosition` so thanks for that! It is worth noting that for machine reals this looks for exact equal, even adding `$MachineEpsilon` will cause it to return `Missing["NotFound"]`.